# Substitution rule for sums of similar objects?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, replacement

Consider objects like

```
obj= (Sum[Subscript[A, i], {i, 1, 5}] Sum[Subscript[A, i], {i, 3, 6}] Sum[Subscript[A, i], {i, 2, 3}])/(
      Sum[Subscript[A, i], {i, 3, 8}] Sum[Subscript[A, i], {i, 1, 2}] Sum[Subscript[A, i], {i, 4, 6}])
```

> [image]

I would like to have a substitution rule `myRule` that would perform the following replacement

```
obj /. myRule
```

> [image]

for sequences of sums of $A_i$ of any lengths, and with indices not necessarily consecutive and not necessarily integer. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
obj /. HoldPattern@Plus@a : (h : Subscript)[A, _] .. :> h[A, ## & @@ Last /@ {a}]
```

It can be even shorter:

```
obj /. HoldPattern@+a : (h : Subscript)[A, _] .. :> h[A, ## & @@ Last /@ {a}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative that will work with subscripted `A`s that have more than one subscript, which may (or may not) be what you want:

```
obj /. HoldPattern[Plus[seq : Subscript[A, __] ..]] :>
  Subscript[A, Sequence @@ Cases[{seq}, Subscript[A, inds__] :> inds]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Block[{Plus = Subscript[#[[1]], ## & @@ (#2 & @@@ {##})] &},  obj] // TeXForm
```

> $\LARGE\frac{A_{2,3} A_{3,4,5,6} A_{1,2,3,4,5}}{A_{1,2} A_{4,5,6} A_{3,4,5,6,7,8}}$

Alternatively,

```
obj /. Plus -> (Subscript[#[[1]], ##&@@(#2&@@@{##})]&) // TeXForm
```

> $\LARGE\frac{A_{2,3} A_{3,4,5,6} A_{1,2,3,4,5}}{A_{1,2} A_{4,5,6} A_{3,4,5,6,7,8}}$